# ibec_ExtractMetadata don't extract tables like "TaSomeData". IBExpert. IBEScript Firebird 2.1

Tags: firebird2.1, ibexpert

I have a problem with the command `ibec_ExtractMetadata` from IBEScript(ibeblock). In my Database most tables have names in InfixCaps like "TaActions", "TaDiscountSystem" etc.

If I use `ibec_ExtractMetadata` with tables in UpperCase - all is well:

```
ibec_ExtractMetadata(OtdelDB, 'd:\DC_Otdel.sql',
         'Domains=NONE; Tables=ACCESSGROUPS; Views=NONE; Triggers=NONE;
          Procedures=NONE; Generators=NONE;
          Exceptions=NONE; UDFs=NONE; Roles=NONE;DataTables=ACCESSGROUPS;
          ExtractBLOBs;UseReinsert; CommitAfter=1000', cbb);
```

But if I want to extract metadata from table "TaDiscountSystem":

```
ibec_ExtractMetadata(OtdelDB, 'd:\DC_Otdel.sql',
         'AlwaysQuoteIdents; Domains=NONE; Tables=NONE; Views=NONE; Triggers=NONE;
          Procedures=NONE; Generators=NONE;
          Exceptions=NONE; UDFs=NONE; Roles=NONE;DataTables=TalmbDiscountSystem;
          ExtractBLOBs; UseReinsert; CommitAfter=1000', cbb);
```

The script output is empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In Firebird mixed case tablenames that are unquoted are stored in uppercase; in queries these object names are case insensitive. Most likely IB Expert expects you to use the tablename as it is stored in the metadata tables for this function. This means: UPPERCASE for unquoted object names or the exact casing of quoted object names.

Comment: Bug from IBExpert http://firebirdexperts.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1152